# QGIS - How to update several rows with triggers SQLite

Tags: qgis, spatialite, sqlite, trigger

I currently have two SpatiaLite layers:

```
HABITATS_POLY: Key fields include EUNIS_1, EUNIS_2, EUNIS_3, EUNIS_4, EUNIS22_1, EUNIS22_2, EUNIS22_3, EUNIS22_4.

GESTION_CODES: Key fields include EUNIS and EUNIS22.
```

I am attempting to create a trigger that will automatically update the fields EUNIS22_1, EUNIS22_2, EUNIS22_3, and EUNIS22_4 in the HABITATS_POLY table based on the values in the EUNIS22 field from the GESTION_CODES table.

The trigger conditions are as follows:
- WHEN EUNIS equals EUNIS_1, set EUNIS22_1 to the value of EUNIS22.
- WHEN EUNIS equals EUNIS_2, set EUNIS22_2 to the value of EUNIS22.
- WHEN EUNIS equals EUNIS_3, set EUNIS22_3 to the value of EUNIS22.
- WHEN EUNIS equals EUNIS_4, set EUNIS22_4 to the value of EUNIS22.

I can make it work when I update a field in HABITATS_POLY, by using this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_eunis22_codes 
AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS_1, EUNIS_2, EUNIS_3, EUNIS_4 ON HABITATS_POLY 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY 
        SET EUNIS22_1 = (SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES 
            WHERE "EUNIS" = NEW.EUNIS_1), 
        EUNIS22_2 = (SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES 
            WHERE "EUNIS" = NEW.EUNIS_2), 
        EUNIS22_3 = (SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES 
            WHERE "EUNIS" = NEW.EUNIS_3), 
        EUNIS22_4 = (SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES 
            WHERE "EUNIS" = NEW.EUNIS_4) 
    
    WHERE EUNIS_1 = NEW.EUNIS_1 OR 
    EUNIS_2 = NEW.EUNIS_2 OR 
    EUNIS_3 = NEW.EUNIS_3 OR 
    EUNIS_4 = NEW.EUNIS_4; 
END;
```

When I insert one feature at a time, I can also have the results I want.

However, when I attempt to insert multiple features simultaneously, only one occurrence of each code is being updated. For instance, if I add 10 features with the EUNIS code 'A1.1' (corresponding to EUNIS22 code 'MA1-46'), only one row gets updated with the EUNIS22 code, while the others remain empty.

I've experimented with various approaches, but so far, I haven't found a solution to this issue.

Here is an example of the result for 7 features with 2 different EUNIS codes. You can see, only 2 features have been updated.
[image: Example]

Here is the last trigger I tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_eunis22_gest
AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS22 ON GESTION_CODES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET
        EUNIS22_1 = NEW.EUNIS22
    WHERE
        EUNIS_1 IN (SELECT EUNIS FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE NEW.EUNIS = EUNIS);

    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET
        EUNIS22_2 = NEW.EUNIS22
    WHERE
        EUNIS_2 IN (SELECT EUNIS FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE NEW.EUNIS = EUNIS);

    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET
        EUNIS22_3 = NEW.EUNIS22
    WHERE
        EUNIS_3 IN (SELECT EUNIS FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE NEW.EUNIS = EUNIS);

    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET
        EUNIS22_4 = NEW.EUNIS22
    WHERE
        EUNIS_4 IN (SELECT EUNIS FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE NEW.EUNIS = EUNIS);
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is to add another trigger when I insert data in the layer HABITATS_POLY.

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_eunis22_codes 
AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY 
BEGIN 
UPDATE HABITATS_POLY 
SET EUNIS22_1 = (SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES 
WHERE "EUNIS" = NEW.EUNIS_1), 
EUNIS22_2 = (SELECT "EUNIS22" 
FROM GESTION_CODES 
WHERE "EUNIS" = NEW.EUNIS_2), 
EUNIS22_3 = (SELECT "EUNIS22" 
FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = NEW.EUNIS_3), 
EUNIS22_4 = (SELECT "EUNIS22" 
FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = NEW.EUNIS_4) 

WHERE EUNIS_1 = NEW.EUNIS_1 OR
 EUNIS_2 = NEW.EUNIS_2 OR
 EUNIS_3 = NEW.EUNIS_3 OR
 EUNIS_4 = NEW.EUNIS_4; 
END;
```

That's a lot of triggers..
Especially if I need to work with several fields.